# Cannot filter a view based on the field value

Tags: drupal, view

Drupal 7

Problem statement: Cannot filter a view based on the field value

1. I have a content type called support ticket
2. It has a field called assigned-to which has the list of users to whom the ticket will be assigned
3. I created a view for support ticket content
4. I have added a contextual filter Content: Assigned to, configured display based on “User ID from logged-in user”
5. Works fine for admin but not for other users

Can anyone please help me resolve this

Answer (score 0):

The setting you're using in the view are perfectly fine. Couple of checks that you could do:

1. Make sure that the field `assinged-to` is a user reference field or an entity reference field reffering to the user entity.
2. Make sure there is value in the `assigned-to` field in some nodes for the current user you're logging in as.